# Signalling Link Selection

Tags: java, ss7

The SLS field determines the distribution of messages across linksets and links as they traverse the network. I cant figure out what does SLS mapping mean in M3UA layer

Comment: What is a linkset? What network are you traversing? What is SLS and M3UA? Please provide a lot more detail so we can help you.

Comment: I need to understand work of m3ua layer and implement it . I read rfc 4666 documentation and my question is that what is SLS and how it used in m3ua layer

Comment: You should add those details to your question. As it stands, your question does not have enough context for anyone to answer it. Also read [ask] for some tips to improve your question in order to find the answers you need.

Answer (score 0):

SLS is used in multi-link scenarios to distribute the traffic evenly. Dialogic has a nice article about it [here](https://www.dialogic.com/webhelp/MSP1010/10.2.3/WebHelp/MSP_DG/SS7/Combined_Link.htm).